# Dynamic CRM "CrmServiceClient" unable to connect using Active Directory Authentication Mode

Tags: c#, active-directory, dynamics-crm-2016

I am trying to connect on premises Dynamic CRM 2016 from asp.net Web Project. I am using CrmServiceClient method with Active Directory Authentication Mode.

I am getting following exception.

> {"Could not load type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PromptBehavior' from assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=3.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.":"Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PromptBehavior"}

```
new CrmServiceClient(
    new System.Net.NetworkCredential("adminuser", "pass", "domain"), 
    Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.AuthenticationType.AD, 
    "http://sample.com", "4466", "DEV", useUniqueInstance:false, 
    useSsl:false)
```

Also Tried this

```
new CrmServiceClient(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRM_CONN"].ConnectionString)
```

Comment: Could you please show the your code?

Comment: @Filburt any suggestion?

Comment: Did you make sure Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll is in place? It sounds like this DLL is missing or maybe blocked by Security Policy because you copied it from a network location.

Comment: It is there, visual studio was giving me exception of this dll. I have added current version 3.10 using nuget. After that it is giving me this exception. It seems that it is internal issue of dll.

Comment: I'd recommend to use the assemblies provided by "crmsdk" in nuget - they should contain correct version. I used them in a console application with the connection string you tried in your second example. My Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll has version 2.18.20625.1556.

Answer (score 9):

Edited, i found the solution.

I had to downgrade: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory to version 2.27 to get this working. 
The newer versions i tested had the same error.

Hope this works for you also!

Comment: Yes, I have also changed the version 2.18. I think, Microsoft is really confused about their versions.

Comment: Got it working with 2.18? I can find 2.18 on my console application, but on my web application i cannot downgrade further than 2.27.

Comment: Only **2.28** works when targeting 4.5.2 version of .NET Framework